# Observe property change in Spring tests

Tags: spring, kotlin, delegates, observer-pattern, kotlin-lateinit

Consider a Service-Bean, that sets a property on some schedule:

```
@Service
class UserService {
    var userInfo: Map<String, UserInfo>? = null

    @Scheduled(...)  
    private fun fetchUserInfo() {
        userInfo = callExternalUserEndpoint()
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I would like to access UserService::userInfo once it has been set by the scheduled function.

My solution so far is to repeatedly call `sleep()`:

```
@SpringBootTest
class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired    
    lateinit var userService: UserService    

    @BeforeEach    
    fun beforeEach() {
        // make sure userInfo not null      
        while (userService.userInfo == null) {
            Thread.sleep(50)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun someTest() {
        // access userService.userInfo ...    
    }
}
```

I have the feeling, that there is a concept or pattern in Kotlin, that achieves this objective in a standardized and elegant way. From consulting the Kotlin documentation, it seems to me, that one should be able to do this using delegated properties, `Delegates.observable()` or a combination of the two. However, I have been unable to make it work. A delegated getter for the lateinit variable could look like:

```
@Component
class Delegate {
    @Autowired    
    lateinit var userService: UserService    

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): String {
        return userService.userInfo.toString()
    }
}
```

Using `Delegates.observable()` , a variable in the test scope can be defined and its changes monitored. How does one connect the two? Something like `Delegates.observable()` , but with a custom getter, that accesses userService.userInfo under the hood?

Comment: If this is related to Spring, you should tag it that way. I'm not familiar with Spring, but `UserService` looks to me like an abuse of `lateinit`. You're using it as a more complicated version of a nullable property, where all the protections of nullability enforcement are removed and the conveniences of nullability operators cannot be used. If it's possible for outside classes to interact with the property before it's initialized, it should be defined as nullable, not `lateinit`. The Delegate class on the other hand looks OK if `@Autowired` hooks it up before you start using the instance.

Comment: As for your question, two possible solutions I see (again I don't know Spring so I'm not sure how best to implement them here). (1) Expose a suspend function `awaitInitialization()` that suspends and returns after the property is initialized. You could do this by using coroutine  in `fetchUserInfo` and joining it in the suspend function (2) Expose a callback function where the callback is fired when the property is ready. How to implement calling a callback on the right thread will depend on the framework you're running on, or you could use a Future.

Comment: With the suspend function version, you might even keep the property private, and return the non-nullable value in `awaitInitialization()` to make the class cleaner to use.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! You are right, of course - I could use a nullable var instead. The issues in the tests remain though: I need to observe, whether the nullable var changes.

Comment: Thank you for these ideas! I have to do some reading and will be back once I fully understand your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Following Tenfour04's advice, I refactored `UserService`, but without using Kotlin coroutines:

```
@Service
class UserService {
    var userInfo: Map<String, UserInfo>? = null
        get() {
            if (field == null) {
                fetchUserInfo()
            }
            return field
        }

    @Scheduled(...)  
    private fun fetchUserInfo() {
        userInfo = callExternalUserEndpoint()
    }
}
```

This way, accessing `userInfo` guarantees that a call to `fetchUserInfo()` has finished before a value is returned, the initialization is encapsulated in `UserService` and an external scope does not have to concern itself with the initialization.